# Google Maps rewrites my link passed to it in a KML file

Tags: html, google-maps, kml

I passed my dataset to Google Maps via a KML file. In the description of the KML file I added a link like *"<a href="www.whatever.com" target="_blank >"* to each KML Placement. When I looked at my placemarks at Google Maps I realized that it changed my target attribute to 'target=_blank'.

Is there a possibility to surpress or avoid rewriting of my url attributes?

Here my KML file:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
   <Document>
      <name>Notarsuche Mobil</name>
         <Placemark>
             <name>Street 30, 1000 Some City</name>
             <description> Steve's Place &lt;a target='_self' href='http://www.steveshome.com' &gt; details &lt;/a&gt; &lt;br /&gt; 
             </description>

                <Style id="normalPlacemark">
                    <IconStyle>
                        <Icon>
                            <href>http://www.linktoanicon.com</href>
                        </Icon>
                    </IconStyle>
                </Style>

                <Point>
                   <coordinates>12.91588070, 46.19427120</coordinates>
                </Point>

            </Placemark>
         </Document>
     </kml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See

- [original link](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps) (no longer valid)
- [updated link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements)

it states:

```
KML Element   | Supported in Google Maps? | Comment
<description> | yes                       | HTML content is allowed but is sanitized to protect from cross-browser attacks; entity replacements of the form $[dataName] are unsupported.
```

See [this message](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/msg/619dbf05ccaa097e) from the Google Maps v2 API group for an explanation by Mike Williams.